# Find intervals in a Pandas DatetimeIndex with continuous data, and with no data in a given period

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, group-by

I have a DatetimeIndex. I would like to find intervals greater than ie '10s' where there are no data, as well as interval with continuous data.

Intervals with data (I show the first one):

```
['2023-09-12 09:48:28.720000', '2023-09-12 09:48:29.020999936']
```

Intervals with no data:

```
['2023-09-12 09:48:29.020999936', '2023-09-19 10:27:00.992000']

index = pd.to_datetime(['2023-09-12 09:48:28.720000',
               '2023-09-12 09:48:28.813999872',
               '2023-09-12 09:48:28.921999872',
               '2023-09-12 09:48:29.020999936',
                  '2023-09-19 10:27:00.992000',
                  '2023-09-19 10:27:01.192000',
               '2023-09-19 10:27:01.293999872'])
```

Comment: Can you post a dictionary -- minimal example -- of how the dataframe looks like at the moment?

Comment: @Guido look at the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a dataframe for clarity:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

ind = pd.to_datetime(['2023-09-12 09:48:28.720000',
                      '2023-09-12 09:48:28.813999872',
                      '2023-09-12 09:48:28.921999872',
                      '2023-09-12 09:48:29.020999936',
                      '2023-09-19 10:27:00.992000',
                      '2023-09-19 10:27:01.192000',
                      '2023-09-19 10:27:01.293999872'])

df = pd.DataFrame({'abc': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]}, index=ind)
```

To obtain intervals without data, index increments in seconds are calculated. And using a Boolean mask, the lines where this increment is more than 10 seconds or the same thing, but with a shift, are selected.

```
delta = df.index.to_series().diff() / np.timedelta64(1, 's')

d = (delta > 10)
no_data = df[(delta.shift(-1) > 10) | d]

print(no_data)
```

Output:

```
                               abc
2023-09-12 09:48:29.020999936    4
2023-09-19 10:27:00.992000000    5
```

and if need array:

```
no_data.index.values
```

For continuous data, a `'cum_sum'` column is created to separate the rows into groups. In this case, where there is an excess of 10 seconds, 1 is set. Next, empty values in the column are replaced with 0. The indexes are reset to be used in the aggregator and the first and last values in each group are obtained.

```
df.loc[d, 'cum_sum'] = 1
df['cum_sum'] = df['cum_sum'].fillna(0).cumsum()

with_data = df.reset_index().groupby(
    'cum_sum', as_index=False)['index'].agg(['first', 'last']
                                            )

print(with_data)
```

Output:

```
   cum_sum                   first                          last
0      0.0 2023-09-12 09:48:28.720 2023-09-12 09:48:29.020999936
1      1.0 2023-09-19 10:27:00.992 2023-09-19 10:27:01.293999872
```

and if need array:

```
print(with_data[['first', 'last']].values)
```

Output:

```
[['2023-09-12T09:48:28.720000000' '2023-09-12T09:48:29.020999936']
 ['2023-09-19T10:27:00.992000000' '2023-09-19T10:27:01.293999872']]
```